# Julia, how to sample from a Truncated Normal distribution?

Tags: julia

How can I sample from a Normal distribution that is truncated at -1 and 1?
I can sample from a Normal distribution by doing

```
using Distributions

rand(Normal())
```

but I'm not sure how to sample from a truncated normal distribution, at least not without an if statement to clip the values myself

Answer (score 5):

`rand(Truncated(Normal()), -1, 1)` will do what you want. See [the docs](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/truncate/) for more info.

Comment: ah yes. Reading the question is a skill.